# How to set up a wireless printer on a computer wired to a Wireless Router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, printer

Well here is my case. I have a brother mfc-9320 wireless printer, a Digisol wireless router & a computer that is wired to the router. I want to set up the wireless printer on the computer in this way that the wireless printer is connected to the router via WLAN & the wired computer on the LAN detects the printer so that it can be installed successfully & print commands given from the computer. I don't know how this sounds or if it is possible. 
Secondly many a times I have heard that all devices have to be wireless in such a scenario.

Well I would really appreciate if a solution was provided to this problem.....

Thanks in advance..

User

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement that all devices have to be wireless is not true. The job of the router that has both wired and wireless connectivity is to allow all connected devices to communicate. This is how the OSI model has come to existence.

If your printer is wireless then it'll connect to your router in the same manner your laptops and other wifi enabled devices connect.

You then install the printer drivers and software on your computer(s)(disk provided or download from manufacturer website) and they should automatically find your printer on the network, add the printer to your "printers and faxes" and then let you print.

It is as simple as that.

On a side note: it is far better to have a network capable printer (wired or wireless) as it means you don't have to share a printer through a computer as this computer will need to be powered on and functioning correctly to guarantee your other computers be able to print. The moment that computer isn't working properly will prevent your entire network from printing. Network capable printers are really cheap nowadays so it's a no brainer!

Comment: Thanks a lot dude. So it is those data packets that are superimposed on radio waves & demodulated at the receiving end

Comment: In a nutshell, yes. Read up the OSI model of networking. Each layer is completely separate so the layer above and below the current layer doesn't need to know about each other. It's all transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible. I understand your topology works like this!

Printer(Wireless)-->WLAN Router-->(LAN)Computer!

So, the IPs are provided by your Wireless Router. With this, you should be able to print. You can get better help from this [doc](https://www.brother-usa.com/VirData/Content/en-US%5CMFC%5CConsumer%5CQuickSetupGuide%5CQSG_MFC_9320CW_EN_1848.PDF)